# CKEditor File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I am using CkEditor in my .NET MVC 3.0 project. I implemented fileupload in CKEditor and its working fine.

Below is the screenshot of Fileupload screen in CKEditor,when I browse and select file then press "send it to server" i want to show "please wait" text instad of File upload control on the same screen or an "Please wait" flash.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Notice: I wrote this plugin.

You could use [the easyupload plugin](http://www.martinezdelizarrondo.com/ckplugins/easyupload.demo/), although at the moment it doesn't apply the progress effect to the default dialogs, only to the ones that it replaces.